# How to cancel alarm by another activity

Tags: android

I have two Activity

in Activity A, I set an alarm

```
public static ActivityA contextA;
Intent intent = new Intent(contextA, AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) contextA
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra("TITLE", triggerTitle);
        PendingIntent ShotSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contextA,
                0, intent, 0);
        manager.setRepeat(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime, fireTime*2 + 
                        system.currentTimeMillis(), ShotSender);
```

in Activity B, i want to cancel the alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.contextA, AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) ActivityA.contextA
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra("TITLE", triggerTitle);
        PendingIntent ShotSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ActivityA.contextA,
                0, intent, 0);
        manager.cancel(ShotSender);
```

but it throws an exception : NullPointerException

happened in Activity B:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.contextA, AlarmReciever.class);
```

is somewhere wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ActivityB's context when creating the Intent. Change the code in ActivityB to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
intent.putExtra("TITLE", triggerTitle);
PendingIntent ShotSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
manager.cancel(ShotSender);
```

Comment: the exception is gone, but the alarm is also not canceled

Comment: Hmmm, try this: use `getApplicationContext()` in both ActivityA and ActivityB as the first parameter to `Intent intent = new Intent(...)` and as the first parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)`

Comment: Your call to the AlarmManager is not correct, maybe that is the cause of the problem. In your post you wrote `setRepeat(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime, fireTime*2 + system.currentTimeMillis(), ShotSender);` but assuming that `fireTime` is the number of milliseconds between alarms the call should be something like this: `setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, system.currentTimeMillis()+fireTime, fireTime*2, ShotSender);`. Please check the documentation for `AlarmManager` and fix your code and try again.

Comment: oh, i forgot to say it, fireTime in my code is millisecond, so repeat time = fireTime*2 + system.currentTimeMillis() is correct format for setRepeat

Comment: No, that's not correct. The repeat time is the number of milliseconds **between** 2 repeats. It can't have `System.currentTimeMillis()` in it. Also the second parameter is the time (in milliseconds) when the first alarm should go off. This parameter must have `System.currentTimeMillis()` in it.

Comment: I don't think it does what you think it does. When you schedule the alarm, you specify `fireTime` as the clock time for the alarm to go off. If this is less than the `System.currentTimeMillis()` the alarm will go off immediately. It also won't repeat as you are using `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the repeat time and this value will be huge. If you want the alarm to repeat every 10 seconds (for example), the repeat time needs to be 10000.